# Initialize field with current year and assigned ID

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I've got an entity that I am persisting. Its ID is automatically assigned when storing it into the database via Spring Repository.
In the same entity, I have a field build from the Id and the current year: `"<current_year>-<id>"`.

In a method annotated with `@PrePersist`, the ID has not been assigned yet, so I wrote some code in a `@PostPersist` method:

```
@PostPersist
protected void setupOrderNumber() {
    this.orderNumber = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + id;
}
```

This code does not store the `orderNumber` into the database, because the entity was stored already.
How can I achieve such a result with JPA directly within the entity?

If not possible with JPA, I could use Hibernate with a `@Formula` annotation, but I am not sure how to write it: `@Formula("extract(year from current_date) + '-' + id")` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already noticed: In `@PrePersist` a generated ID is not available - just because the ID is set afterwards when persisting into the database. And no changes made in `@PostPersist` are persisted, just because the persist has already taken place...

You can use a `@Formula`, as long you don't need the value in the database. But I wouldn't use `extract(year from current_date)` - as this would change the `orderNumber` when the year changes - what is different to your experiment with `@PostPersist`.

Instead use a year field, which you initialize in `@PrePersist` and reference that one in your formula:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(...)
  private Long id;

  private int year;

  @Formula("concat(id, '-', year)")
  private String orderNumber;

  @PrePersist
  private void prePersist() {
     this.year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
  }

  @PostPersist
  private void postPersist() {
     this.orderNumber = id + "-" + year;
  }

}
```

I initialize the `orderNumber` in `postPersist()` as well, to have a valid value immediately after `EntityManager.persist()`.